# Vector Graphics for Textbooks

Tags: graphics

I am editing a math textbook with a lot of graphs and plots. I'd like to know if it's better to draw these figures outside of latex (using Matlab for example) and import them using `\includegraphics` or draw them directly using internal libraries like tikz. The former is easier, of course, but they don't look uniform with my overall color scheme and the thickness of lines doesn't adjust automatically with size. The latter looks more professional but is really messy in coding. Any advice on this? What is your preference?

I know some publishers like Springer require figures to be independent from the TeX file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is opinion-based or depends on the specific needs. There's no better or worse of pursuing this or that approach (in the final end, it's most times a mixture of all ways ;-))

Comment: Thanks. But is there a prettier and more systematic way for creating graphics?

Comment: In my option, if possible, always use vector format.

Comment: vector graphics are certainly preferable.  you might consider creating your graphics separately with `tikz`, and calling them in with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: If you are a R user, [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) is a very good option  because  the  `tikzDevice package` makes the font styles in plots consistent with the document class, beside that  R can produce also LaTeX code in the plots or outside the plots (i,e., tables, etc.) , and overall, that data manipulation and plotting R code is in the same file that text with LaTeX code, and therefore if data source changed in a csv file, you need only compiling again your document  to update all the plots (and tables, and even the text) accordingly.

Comment: I second barbara beeton....create your figures separately according to their various needs (via vector graphics) and then import them into your .tex file. In this manner, your figures would be need-specific and would make your editing much more easier in the long run. I have put off writing a book for adults in mathematics for this specific reason...each figure displays something specific and so require individual tailoring.

Comment: In my opinion, TikZ is one of the nicest-looking ways to draw figures for LaTeX. The package pgfplots and the command tikzexternalize will certainly help, as well as defining own styles and macros for drawing and plotting.

Comment: I have a 300 page math course (functions, goniometry, statistics, geometry, complex numbers, ...) and every single drawing is made in tikz IN the main document. The main advantage is... if I want to change a drawing, I don't have to find the separate drawing, because I it is IN the master document.